# Vue JS: Data shows duplicated from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my Vue js i have JSON data from API and i'm showing those data on my project.. my problem is each data appears two times when i run code below and i couldin't figure out the problem until now.. i might did something wrong here .
below is my JSON response and what i want to show is the data inside array `installments`

```html
{ 
"payment" : { "installment_payment" : { "installments" : [ { 
"paid_amount": "5000", "date" : "2021-12-21" }, 
{ "paid_amount": "4000", "date" : "2021-12-21" } ],
"remaining" : "1000" } }, 
"status" : "Booked" }
```

and my code below is for showing data response saved in Flats array:

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import moment from 'moment'

Vue.prototype.moment = moment
// Charts
import * as chartConfigs from '@/components/Charts/config';
import LineChart from '@/components/Charts/LineChart';
import BarChart from '@/components/Charts/BarChart';

// Components
import BaseProgress from '@/components/BaseProgress';
import StatsCard from '@/components/Cards/StatsCard';

// Tables
import SocialTrafficTable from './Dashboard/SocialTrafficTable';
import PageVisitsTable from './Dashboard/PageVisitsTable';
import BuildingsService from "@/services/ApiService"
export default {
    components: {
        LineChart,
        BarChart,
        BaseProgress,
        StatsCard,
        PageVisitsTable,
        SocialTrafficTable
    },
    data() {
        return {
            Flats: [],
            cityName: '',
            buildings: [],
  
        };
    },

  
    mounted() {
      // API calls

        BuildingsService.getBuildings().then((response) => {
            this.buildings = response.data.response;

        });

        BuildingsService.getAllFlats().then((response) => {
            this.Flats = response.data.response;

        });

    },

};
```

```html
<b-card-body class="px-lg-5 py-lg-5">
                        <div class="text-center text-muted mb-4">
                            <div v-for="(flat,index) in Flats" :key="index" >

                                <div class="instPayment mt-4" v-for="(findf,index) in flat.payment" :key="index+'compo'" v-if="flat.payment.installment_payment">
                                    <h2 v-for="(building,indexb) in buildings" :key="indexb" > 
                                    <span  v-if="building._id.includes(flat.building)"> ({{building.building_number}}) building no ({{flat.flat_number}}) no flat </span></h2>

                                    <h3>paymens amount:</h3>
                                    <b-row class="text-align" v-for="(find,index)  in flat.payment.installment_payment.installments" :key="'analyte'+index">
                                    <b-col> <p>{{find.paid_amount}}$ </p></b-col>
                                   
                                       <b-col><p :class="{ 'text-red': currentDate > find.date, 'text-green': currentDate == find.date}"> {{find.date}} </p></b-col> 

                                    </b-row>
                                    <b-button :to="`/EditFlat/${flat._id}`"> edit </b-button>

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <validation-observer ref="formValidator">

                        </validation-observer>
                    </b-card-body>
```

edit: each data appears twice like if i have payment amount in flat no1 and building no1 it appears two times with same payment info

Comment: the json you show is a single item in Flats, so for each item you loop over each payment which is why for each payment it shows a flat, we went over this yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70558185/vue-js-data-duplicated-when-api-called

Comment: i closed yesterday's question ... problem still not solved i couldn't find out why it's repeating data twice,,, if you have an answer please provide it @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that pops for me here by reading your snippets is the usage of **v-if** in the same element of a **v-for** loop. It is not recommended. You have to create a parent element that contains the conditional.

The second potential problem could be the repeated loop for **"flat.payment"** on that **"b-row"**. You already have a loop for **"flat.payment"** there is no need for another. Just use the data from the first loop.

Comment: i tried to use one loop only and still repeating the flatno and building no + when i used one loop only it gives the error undefined reading of installments

Comment: in other words.. i can't access data `installments` without looping on both flat.payment.installment_payment.installments and flat.payment

Comment: So, I guess the loop you need on that b-row is not from flat.payment. it is from "findf.installment_payment.installments"

Comment: still same error appears ` can't read data of installments`

Comment: I need to confess that I'm getting lost here hahah. By looking to your snippets, the only thing I see that could lead to an error after fixing what we discussed is the "b-col" trying to read "find.amount" when the correct reading would be "find.paid_amount"

Comment: i'm lost too :(  i corrected that too it's not the problem :/